# How to make the later Promises wait for the first Promise to finish in bluebird?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I'm trying to chain Promises. Here's the code

```
crawler.cache(url).then(function (cRes) {
  console.log('get from cache');      
  if(cRes) {
    return Promise.resolve(JSON.parse(cRes));
  } else { 
    console.log('no cache');
    crawler.db(url).then(function (result) {
      console.log('get from db');
      return Promise.resolve(JSON.parse(result));
    });
  }
}).then(function fetch(someResult) {
  console.log('fetch data from' + someResult);
});
```

What I'm hoping is that it would look into the `cache` first if it couldn't find then it should look in to `db`. And then pass the result to the last `then` which to fetch the result.

But here's what printing from my console.

```
get from cache
no cache
fetch data from null
get from db
```

First it couldn't find anything in the cache then it's trying to fetch from the database but it didn't wait until getting from the db is done it went on to `fetch data`.

How do I solve this problem when the last `then` has to wait for everything above it to finish to get the result then it can do the next operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just return the promise inside the `then` continuation, this will cause the parent promise to wait until the returned promise is fulfilled and adopt it's value.

There is also no need to use the `Promise.resolve` method, you can just return the value directly.

```
crawler.cache(url).then(function (cRes) {
    if (cRes) {
        console.log('cache result');
        return JSON.parse(cRes);
    } else {
        console.log('no cache');
        return crawler.db(url).then(function (result) {
            return JSON.parse(result);
        });
    }
}).then(function fetch(someResult) {
    console.log('fetch data from' + someResult);
});
```

Bonus:
If you are storing your cache in memory. you probably don't need to return a promise from your `crawler.cache` function.

Answer (score -2):

OT: I'd recomend you a slightly different approach. Use the rejection-path of the promises to communicate that a Value is not available/couldn't be resolved or provided.

This way it would be more intuitive wether a (possibly falsy) value is provided or, wether we have to resolve that from a different source like the db.

Sth. like (pseudocode):

```
crawler.cache = function(url){
    //you will have to adapt this part to your structure.
    //but you get the idea?
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        if(url in _cache){
            resolve( _cache[url] );
        }else{
            //you can simply reject() without a reason,
            //or you can return an Error-Object, or some message, or whatever ...
            reject({ message: "no cache for " + url });
        }
    });
}

//try to access the value from the cache
crawler.cache(url)
    //if the cache fails (to provide you a value), 
    //try to resolve the value from the db
    .catch(() => crawler.db(url).then(saveToCache)) 

    //parse the result, wether it is from the cache or the db
    //maybe you want to add a second argument to catch the case where the db also fails?
    .then(str => JSON.parse(str));
    //maybe you want to add a catch here, 
    //in case JSON.parse is provided sth false, like a damaged string?
```

Comment: Don't use exceptions as part of your interface. Also the cache you are using here is fully synchronous, it doesn't make sense to wrap a promise around it.

Comment: I agree with your argument, but i'm not sure wether it applies to this case. Rejecting a promise is not exactly the same thing as throwing an Error. The fact that the rejection-track is used to handle Errors in promises, doesn't mean that it is exclusive to this one purpose.

Comment: Throwing an error is exactly the same as rejecting an Promise from in interface point of view. Take a look at ES 7 coroutines if you want to learn more about that.